# Restructure mongodb return data for the react native's SectionList

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

Im using Node JS (backend) and react native (frontend).

I need pass all the transaction record to my react native and show into **SectionList**.

This is my transaction Schema:

```
const transactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    customer_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer'
    },
    customer_name: {
        type: String
    },
    reference_code: {
        type: String
    },
    send_currency: {
        type: String
    },
    send_amount: {
        type: Number
    },
    receive_currency: {
        type: String
    },
    receive_amount: {
        type: Number
    },
    transaction_fees: {
        type: Number
    },
    conversion_rate: {
        type: Number
    },
    beneficiary_name: {
        type: String
    },
    // Bank
    beneficiary_bank_name: {
        type: String
    },
    beneficiary_bank: {
        type: String
    },
    beneficiary_account_number: {
        type: String
    },
    transaction_latest_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    },
    transaction_latest_status: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    }
});
```

The following query fetches all the transaction record

```
db.collection('transaction').find({ 'transaction_latest_date': { "$gte": new Date(req.body.start_date), "$lte": new Date(req.body.end_date) } }, callback)
```

I hope I can get the result like this:

```
[
    {
        "date": "01/08/2022",
        "data": [
            {
                "reference_code": "AAAA",
                "send_amount": "100"
                // .... other relevant data in the transaction such as customer name, currency and more
            },
            // ... more transaction data
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "02/08/2022",
        "data": [
            {
                "reference_code": "BBBB",
                "send_amount": "200"
                // .... other relevant data in the transaction such as customer name, currency and more
            },
            // ... more transaction data
        ]
    }
]
```

OR do I need to restructure the data in the frontend instead of in the backend?

I hope can get some advice. Thank you

Comment: What does the schema for the collection look like?

Comment: It is possible to re-structure the data in the backend using the _projection_ in the MongoDB query. Projection allows transforming the data, limiting the fields, etc.

Comment: @StephenTaylor, please check again. I have edited my post